# Proper way to join these tables?

Tags: php, join, mysqli

I am attempting to learn the difference in `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. I watched several youtube videos and researched Google. However, I can't quite grasp why my JOIN query is not working. If I run the sql I get `Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`.

**sales table**

```
sales_id   user_id   amount    date         status
3          1         1258.32   2013-07-02   S
```

**users table**

```
user_id   fname   lname
1         John    Doe
```

**My Code:**

```
$top = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_id, fname, lname, SUM(amount) as total 
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN users ON
user_id.sales = user_id.users
WHERE status = 'S' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($top)) {
           $topamount[]     = $row['total'];
           $topfnameuser[]  = $row['fname'];
           $toplnameuser[]  = $row['lname'];
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `sales` and `users` have a column named `user_id`, you have to be specific in your `SELECT` list about which you want:

```
SELECT sales.user_id as user_id, fname, lname, SUM(amount) as total 
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN users
ON sales.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE status = 'S' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

You also had the table and column names backwards in the `ON` clause. It's `table.column`, not `column.table`

Comment: Thanks once again!! You rock!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have miss understanding with the using of LEFT JOIN,
Try this..
I have create table like you want, and I have error if i use your query and solve it so the query like this

```
SELECT fname,lname, SUM(amount) AS total
  FROM users LEFT JOIN sales
  ON users.user_id = sales.user_id
    WHERE sales.status = 'S' AND MONTH(sales.date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(sales.date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the "attempting to learn the difference in `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`" part, outer joins are useful when you want to see all rows from one table, even those that have no corresponding rows in another related table.

Here's a simple example using students and test grades.

```
create table students (student_id serial primary key, student_name text);
create table tests (test_id serial primary key, test_name text, test_date date);
create table grades (
    student_id int,
    test_id int,
    grade char,
    primary key (student_id, test_id),
    foreign key (student_id) references students (student_id),
    foreign key (test_id) references tests (test_id));

insert into students (student_name) values ('joe');
insert into students (student_name) values ('amber');
insert into students (student_name) values ('steve');

insert into tests (test_name, test_date) values ('test 1', '2013-01-20');
insert into tests (test_name, test_date) values ('test 2', '2013-02-10');

insert into grades (student_id, test_id, grade) values (1, 1, 'A');
insert into grades (student_id, test_id, grade) values (1, 2, 'B');
insert into grades (student_id, test_id, grade) values (2, 1, 'B');
insert into grades (student_id, test_id, grade) values (2, 2, 'A');
```

The following query would return a list of students and their grades, including one row identifying students without any grades yet (in this case, Steve):

```
select s.student_name, t.test_name, t.test_date, g.grade
from students as s
left join grades as g on s.student_id = g.student_id
left join tests as t on g.test_id = t.test_id;

student_name | test_name | test_date  | grade 
--------------+-----------+------------+-------
joe          | test 1    | 2013-01-20 | A
joe          | test 2    | 2013-02-10 | B
amber        | test 1    | 2013-01-20 | B
amber        | test 1    | 2013-01-20 | A
steve        |           |            | 
(5 rows)
```

One really useful way to use outer joins is when you want to see **only** rows without matching rows in the related table.  You can also do this with a subquery, but using an outer join isn't a bad option:

```
select s.student_name                                   
from students as s
left join grades as g on s.student_id = g.student_id
where g.student_id is null;
student_name 
--------------
steve
(1 row)
```

...is functionally equivalent to:

```
select student_name from students where student_id not in (select student_id from grades); 
student_name 
--------------
steve
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `JOIN` when a given id is in both tables that you are joining.

You use `LEFT JOIN` when a given id is in one table and maybe in the second one

In your case you should select from users and left join sales

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, SUM(s.amount) as total 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE s.status = 'S' AND MONTH(s.date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(s.date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Note the alias in table naming (users u). Then with that alias you can specify which column from which table to select.

Also I will recommend not to name a column "date" because it's a reserved word by MySQL. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a table alias so you can refer to it when referencing fields. Your issue is you have `user_id` in both tables and you have not defined which table to read the user_id from.

```
"SELECT s.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, SUM(s.amount) as total 
FROM sales AS s
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON
s.user_id = u.user_id
```